# After animation of view, setOnClicklistener function stopped working

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-animation

I'm making an animation of the disappearance of a layout with buttons

```
    b.keyboard.clearAnimation()
    b.keyboard.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this@MainActivity, R.anim.move))
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({ //Animation runs 200 milliseconds
        b.keyboard.visibility = View.GONE
        }, 200)
```

Then I animate the appearance of the layout and after that the layout itself with the buttons stopped working and was pressed

```
b.keyboard.visibility = View.VISIBLE
b.keyboard.clearAnimation()
b.keyboard.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.unmove))
```